# How can I install a specialist package of metafonts on TeX Live?

Tags: fonts, packages, installing, metafont

I'm new on LaTeX, can you tell me how to install `byzfonts` ("Byzantine Music Font") on TeX Live? I've downloaded it from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/byzfonts), but there is no installation manual for it.

[ADDED by cfr]

I started trying to answer this but I can't understand the package well enough.

There are a lot of files here and the file names don't make sense to me. For example, the `.sty` files are certainly not LaTeX packages. So they are 'style' files in some other sense I'm not familiar with. Moreover, there do not seem to be any `.fd` files to support the use of the fonts with LaTeX, although there is certainly support for LaTeX in `.tex` files defining new commands.

Are these meant to be installed as fonts at all? Or are they meant to be used in some other way?

Comment: Which platform do you use? Windows, Mac OS X, Linux?

Comment: Crosspost to [LaTeX Community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=25778&p=88002#p88001).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I started to write an answer to this but I've given up. Do any of the documents say anything about what to do with things? The `.sty` files are not `.sty` files of any kind familiar to me. That is, they are not LaTeX packages at all. They look more like plain TeX. (You can use these in LaTeX, too, but they are not 'style' files as the README claims.) There don't appear to be any `.fd` files. So you'd need to create these unless they have been misnamed or are hidden in one of the sub-directories.

Comment: This is not going to be an easy installation. How badly do you need these particular fonts? Are there any alternatives you could use? If you absolutely need them, which ones specifically do you need? Are you aware that these fonts will not look good if used in PDF documents viewed with certain PDF viewers (e.g. Adobe)? If the fonts are good, they should print fine. But the results won't be good for use in e.g. PDFs posted online or by email.

Comment: I've added some specifics to the question. If you prefer, feel free to roll-back my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me on MacOSX (you didn't specify your own platform yet):

- Install the `STY` and `Defs` directories into the `tex` directory of your personal TEXMF directory (here on MacOSX in `~/Library/texmf/tex/byzfonts`, arborescence to be created if needed, on other Unixes it would be probably `~/texmf/tex/byzfonts`);
- Install the `Alphabet` folder, the XAP folders and the `byyf.mf`, `byzf.mf`, `bzal.mf` files in the `~/Library/texmf/fonts/source/byzfonts` directory (also create this arborescence if needed);

Note: `~` stands for your personal HOME directory, that is `/Users/<your_username>` on MacOSX.

You can choose to install those files in you local texmf directory instead, `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` on MacOSX (and other Unixes as well it seems), but then you'll have to enter, after the previous steps, the `mktexlsr` or `texhash` instruction on the command line, as a "super user" (in MacOSX, `sudo mktexlsr`).

If I compile the file `tst.tex` I get this:

[image]

Comment: @wakajawaka I forgot to mention that the XAP folders must also go to `~/Library/texmf/fonts/source/byzfonts` (or probably rather to `~/texmf/fonts/source/byzfonts` since you are on Linux), since they also contain Metafont files. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your reply which command is in latex  *.tex  to define my font? i use linux texlive: i've made folders ~/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/source/byzfonts and install here Alphabet folder and other folders including files with type *.mf  ;  and also i've  installed in ~/usr/local/share/texmf/   folder Defs and STY. now what should i do?

Comment: You seem to make a confusion between `~/texmf` and `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`. Which one have you chosen?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. If you indeed have done all the installations I previously told, i.e. in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/source/byzfonts` and `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/byzfonts`, the only thing remaining to be done is updating the filename database, by entering the command `mktexlsr` as a ‘‘super user’’. On Mac OS X, this is done by entering `sudo mktexlsr` which will require a administrator password. On Linux, this may be similar.

Comment: You can choose either (but not both). See also my comment above.

Comment: ok, ive updated  database, now please tell me how to define this fonts in *.tex file.

Comment: As for this, I can't answer. The only thing I did about this was to check that my installation worked, by executing the file `tst.tex`. There seems to be a lot of other examples, maybe you should try to see how they invoke the fonts.

Comment: maybe Ive Poorly explained you this last request. : last thing I want  is to define this fonts in tex file: I don't know there are different command like usepackage, usefont ,i.e.  if you'll help me to do this  then I will work with text independently.

Comment: As `cfr` already noticed, these fonts are not organized the way a classical LaTeX font package usually is. They don't follow the usual scheme, e.g. they are not simply called by `\usepackage{thefont}` and so on. Really, I don't know anymore than you do about this. The only advice I can give you is to study how the given example files (`test.tex` and co.) call the fonts and understand the logic behind this (which I don't understand myself).

Comment: (+1) but 2 suggestions. (1) I think that the use of 'arborescence` makes things needlessly difficult for users whose English is less than perfect. (2) It would be more effective, more accurate and more efficient to suggest users run `kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME` and install into e.g. `$(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME)/tex/byzrfonts`. On unices, `mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME)/fonts/source/byzrfonts` would create that directory. You can then say that another option is to use `TEXMFLOCAL` which reduces the risk of confusion with the main `texmf` tree.

Comment: @wakajawaka You are using your distro's TeX Live packages, right? So `kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL` gives you a different result from fpast? I'm assuming that it gives you `/usr/local/share/texmf/`. However, if you really installed under `~/usr/local/share/texmf/` then that's almost certainly wrong. This would be e.g. `/home/yourusername/usr/local/share/texmf` which is probably not what you get it you run `kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME`.