# Installing specialist "metsymb" font via Tex Live Utility leads to LookupError

Tags: fonts, texlive, installing, ctan, installing-fonts

The metsymb package was just uploaded to [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/metsymb). This is the final stage in a long process to include (custom) vectorial symbols in Python plots via LaTeX - and for which I already got a lot of help from the hivemind [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610992), [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68769147), and [over there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611746).

I am able to install the font manually using the instructions listed [in the Github repo](https://github.com/MeteoSwiss/metsymb#install-metsymb-as-a-latex-package). I (naïvely ?) thought that with the package on CTAN, I could then install it more easily using Tex Live Utility.

Sadly, although the installation was "successful" according to Tex Live Utility:

1. I cannot run the `metsymb_mwe.py` [MWE](https://github.com/MeteoSwiss/metsymb/blob/develop/source/metsymb_mwe.py), which gives me the following error:

```
LookupError: An associated PostScript font (required by Matplotlib) could not be found
for TeX font 'metsymb' in '/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map'; 
this problem can often be solved by installing a suitable PostScript font package in
your TeX package manager
```

2. Trying to plot any symbol using LaTeXiT fails with the following log message:

   ```
   LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/metsymb/m/n' undefined
   (Font)              using `U/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 8.

   [1{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
   (./latexit-1.aux)

   LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
   ```

Which begs the question: **is something wrong with the metsymb package** (that prevents a successful automatic install), or **is it simply not possible to install a package like metsymb with Tex Live Utility** ?

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232809) indirectly suggests the latter. But surely, there is something I could improve in metsymb to enable a working automatic install via package managers ?

Running OSX 13.0 with a fresh MacTeX 2023 install.

Comment: the installation in texlive is faulty, the umetsymb.fd is missing and the map file has not been activated. If I correct both it works. Write to the texlive mailing list, then it should be ok tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion @Ulrike Fischer !

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [@Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer), the problem was on the Tex Live side of things. The CTAN/Tex Live gurus could fix the problem (after I contacted them), and the metsymb package can now be installed without issues.